# RS232 Communication Issue with SerialPort : DataRecieved Event not firing (VS2008)

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I am using VS2008 SerialPort V2.0.0.0. There is absolutely no back or forth communication.

I know the code works because the same application is running on a different client's machine. 
I know the driver for serial-to-usb cable works because I set it up on vb6 mscomm application and I DO get communication. 
I know I'm setting up the cables right, null modem and everything, because I got communication in vb6 application.
I thought it was a Windows 7 issue so I installed my application on a XP and still doesn't work.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there a certain service pack component needed to run SerialPort v2.0.0.0? Should I try VS 2010, will it make a difference?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at your code to see if you're suppressing an error that would tell you what is happening?

Comment: I put a breakpoint on the datarecieved event. It's not firing, it seems it never gets to that point.

Comment: What about the code that initializes and opens the port?

Comment: the code that opens and initializes the port is also ok. i tried outputting a character with no error. not that it gets to the receiving machine but it doesn't complain on output. when the ports not initialized it won't allow you to serialport.output.

Answer (score 0):

you have tagged this as vb6, although it seems you are using vb.net

in case you are using vb6 : what are the properties of the mscomm control ?

make sure the RThreshold and SThreshold properties are both 0

Answer (score 0):

i don't use vb.net but in c# i use the datareceived event of a serialport control as follows :

```
    private void comKAR_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    //process incoming RS232 data
    {
        byte[] bytArray;
        int intCount;
        intCount = comKAR.BytesToRead;
        bytArray = new byte[intCount];
        comKAR.Read(bytArray,0,intCount);
        ShowData(bytArray);
        ShowTraffic(bytArray,1);
    }
```

the properties of the serialport control are not different from the default properties which it gets upon placing on the form